# C3.js legends are overlapping when hiding/showing div. How to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

When I load a page, a fairly simple chart is generated:

```
function showSetters() {

   $("#div1").show();
   chartRef.flush();

}

function showHatchers() {
   $("#div1").show();
   
}

$("#div1").hide();

var chartRef = createChart();

function createChart() {
    var chart = bb.generate({          
        bindto: "#div1",
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['Months', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ],
            types: {
                Months: 'bar',
            }
        },
        axis: {
            rotated: true
        }
    });
}
```

This chart is loaded in 
Works perfectly fine.
However when I first do a $("#div1").hide(); and, after the chart is created, a $("#div1").show(); The legends are overlapping.

With the flus() addition it gives:
"Cannot read property flush of undefined" What am I missing?

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

It'll be miscalculating bounds if the div is hidden and you create a chart in it. Try calling flush() on the chart after showing the div it's contained in

https://jsfiddle.net/5k0hjnmt/

```
function createChart() {
    var chart = c3.generate({          
        bindto: "#div1",
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['Months', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ],
            types: {
                Months: 'bar',
            }
        },
        axis: {
            rotated: true
        }
    });
    
    return chart;
} 

$("#div1").hide();
  
var chartRef = createChart();

$("#div1").show();

chartRef.flush();   // comment this out for a blank chart
```

Comment: HI @mgraham  I changed my initial question with your addition but  chartRef is not defined. What am I missing?

Comment: return chart from the createChart() function

Comment: Archh, indeed. The error went away. However the problem was not solved. Still overlapping. I don't get it.

Comment: This does work but not very nice:

chartRef.resize() // this makes the chart visible

chartRef.internal.clearLegendItemTextBoxCache(); // clears the cached dimensions

chartRef.internal.resetCache();

chartRef.resize();